# Am I able to export ArcGIS Pro temporal data into one table of duplicates?

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, arcpy, temporal

Stuck on a project at work. I have 1 layer of temporal data in ArcPro with start/stop times. I'm trying to categorize them into 10 minute bins, but some of their durations of time span over 30 minutes or multiple hours. If I use the timeslider and step through the data in 10 minute increments, I get the attribute table to filter for those records.

I want a full table of data with these records in 10 minute increments (with duplicates for those who fall into multiple 10-minute bins). How can I get this easily without stepping through the timeslider and copying/pasting each attribute table into Excel? Is there a tool which would allow me to concatenate all these into 1 large table? Is there a python script I can write? HELP!

I haven't tried any code yet...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.